# Access Gmail data of another account using app script

Tags: google-apps-script, authorization

I am creating one app script for creating an application. The application is simple, one user authenticate the script and the script collects the inbox and other  statistics of the Gmail user. Everything is working fine with the below query:

```
function getQuery(e){ //Working perfect for inbox and draft messages
var inc = 400;
var start = 0;
var totalMessage = 0;
do  {
  var thread = GmailApp.search(e,start, inc); 
  var messages = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(thread);
  totalMessage += messages.length;
  start += inc;
  }  while (thread.length == inc);
return totalMessage;
}
```

Everything works fine when any user runs the application, but I am not sure, is it possible so that, the admin(or developer) of the script can run the script to get access of the another user Gmail data (Surely those who have already gave authorization). 
Actually I need to know, is it possible so that, say **xyz@gmail.com** is the developer and **abc@gmail.com** has authorised the script to run, then **xyz@gmail.com** can run the query to get data from **abc@gmail.com** account?

Answer (score 0):

it is possible but you will need to do a rewrite. instead of using the native authentication and gmail appscript apis you would need to do allxyhe oauth2 yourself and the gmail apis yourself using the rest api. it takes some work and knowledge of how the oauth flow works (which would be too broad to answer here).